# How do I correctly prepend an int in a singly linked list (C)?

Tags: c

I have this struct defined in my .c file:

```
typedef struct node
{
    // the value to store in this node
    int i;

    // the link to the next node in the list
    struct node* next;
}
node;
```

I wrote a prepend function that I can use in a for loop in main to test some values:

```
void prepend(int i)
{
    node* newNode = NULL;
    if(first->next == NULL)
    {
        newNode->i = i;
        first->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next = first->next;
        newNode->i = i;
        first->next = newNode;      
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I get a Segmentation Fault when running the program.

Edit: I get the error when the program reach if(first->next == NULL)

Comment: Where and how `first` is initialized and declared?

Comment: You (almost) cannot get a Segmentation Fault when compiling. You mean when running.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, I get the SIGSEV when running the program, sorry.

Comment: Did you mean to insert the new value as the first in the list (prepend) or as the last in the list (append) or in the middle (insert)?  You seem to be inserting it second in the list.  Or maybe my confusion is that you are using an allocated node in first to hold a pointer to the actual start of the list as first->next?  Normally, first would be a pointer to the first node itself and would be NULL if the list is empty.  It can also be a good idea to keep a last pointer if you would ever need to append to the end of the list--to save on walking--but maybe you don't need that for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code dereferences a `NULL` pointer, called `newNode`, in both branches of the `if/else`. Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behaviour, in this case a segmentation fault. Allocate memory, using [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), for `newNode` before using it:

```
node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
if (newNode)
{
    newNode->i = i; /* No need to repeat this in both branches. */
    /* ... snip ... */
}
```

`first` must also being pointing to a valid `node` before it is used. Remember to [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) whatever is `malloc()`d when no longer required.

Comment: If first has been declared as a global variable and initialized as NULL does it mean that I should also malloc it too?

Comment: @Eros, If first is being allocated to manage the list rather than to hold an actual node of the list then perhaps it is incorrectly named (and could perhaps be a different type than the nodes themselves are, but that isn't absolutely necessary).